# Sql Counting rows for two columns where col1 same as col2

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm breaking my head in combining next two queries in one:

```
SELECT Data1, COUNT(Data1) FROM Table GROUP BY Data1 ORDER BY Data1;
SELECT Data2, COUNT(Data2) FROM Table GROUP BY Data2 ORDER BY Data2;
```

so result will look like:

```
data1 count1 data2 count2
Alpha 22     Alpha 32 
Delta 33     Delta 44
```

or

```
data1 count1 count2
Alpha 22     32 
Delta 33     44
```

Seems like I dont have enough knowlege to complete it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT Data1, COUNT(Data1) FROM Table GROUP BY Data1) d1
  JOIN (SELECT Data2, COUNT(Data2) FROM Table GROUP BY Data2 ORDER BY Data2) d2
    ON d1.Data1 = d2.Data2
  ORDER BY d1.Data1;
```

Comment: Right. But maybe it would be better using OUTER JOIN here, in other case query loses some records if opposite count is empty.

Comment: Thank for your help, this what i wanted, for the best result i have to remove data2 column, but i think i can handle it myself, thants again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.Data1, t1.Count1, t1.Data2, t1.Count2 
FROM (SELECT Data1, COUNT(Data1) as Count1 FROM Table GROUP BY Data1) t1,
FROM (SELECT Data2, COUNT(Data2) AS Count2 FROM Table GROUP BY Data2) t2
WHERE t1.Data1 = t1.Data2
ORDER BY t1.Data1
```

Comment: You should always use explicit joins instead of this implicit joins

Comment: @Lamak Why? This is a natural join proper ANSI SQL, in the end it does not make a difference, since the optimizer will produce the exact same  query anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i couldnt get it working: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (SELECT Data2, COUNT(Data2) AS Count2 FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

A quickest (but probably not the best) solution that came to my mind is given below

```
(Select "Data1", Data1 As DataSource1, Count(data1) As Count from mytable Group by data1)
Union 
(Select "Data2", Data2 As DataSource2, Count(data2) As Count from mytable group by Data2);
```

Try it, its much efficient than joins. Hope it will work good to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it feels like this one show rows like 'Data1'|Data1|COUNT(summ of 1st query and 2nd)

Answer (score 0):

Although more of clarification of data than an answer... It SOUNDS like there just a value in columns "Data1" of Alpha or Delta, and also "Data2" has Alpha or Delta? and you just want the totals per respective first or second position the value is appearing?

```
such as 
Data1   Data2
Alpha   Alpha
Alpha   Delta
Alpha   Delta
Delta   Alpha

with a result of 
Alpha  3    2
Delta  1    2
```

Although the other queries provided do offer solutions, I'm wondering if you actually have MORE values than just the two and need even more rows based on possibly more data values within the respective columns.

Could you please confirm in case the other answers do not provide what you ultimately are looking for.

Comment: >'It SOUNDS like there just a value in columns "Data1" of Alpha or Delta, and also "Data2" has Alpha or Delta? and you just want the totals per respective first or second position the value is appearing?' Thanks for helping. Yes You are right, but with my basics in sql i couldnt find better way to count Same Strings in columns and show it like in your example. The closest solution by now is from VeeArr, but may it can be more simply?

Comment: @user1189049, Not too much simpler than VeeArr, I would up-check his answer and mark it as the solution too so people know the question is solved.